# What is the sum of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

The series is as follows:

$$\lg n + lg (n - 2) + lg (n - 4) + \ldots + lg (2)$$

Thanks.

Comment: From the pattern, do you know $n$ is even?

Comment: I don't know whether it is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $n$ is even. We write $n=2k$, then your series is $$\sum_{i=1}^k \ln(2i)=\ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^k 2i\right)=k\ln2+\ln(k!)$$I don't think there is a nicer expression for this...

Comment: I think the correct answer is k(ln 2) + ln([k/2]!)

Comment: I think you mean $k\ln2+\ln([n/2]!)$, which is the same as my solution as $k=n/2$. Otherwise I think my equation is correct, but if you see a mistake let me know.

Comment: You are right. I missed the n = 2k part.